# How to test a Facebook application on Google App Engine locally (code 191 error)?

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-apps

I want to test and develop locally, while having the application on the air, and I'd rather not use two separate application id's because this means I have to change the code every time I deploy a new version and then change it back.

I understand that I can change the host file so that `localdev.{{my application URL}}` would refer to localhost and the URL will be valid, so I won't get the 191 code, but the Google App Engine launcher forces me to use port 8080, and this can't be defined in the host files. If I try to enter `localdev.{{my application URL}}:8080` I get the 191 error code again.

Is there any way to use port 80 with the Google App Engine launcher?

Or is there another solution?

UPDATES:

1. I managed to run locally on port 80 by using the Python file from the Google App Engine directory and not the Google App Engine launcher GUI. However, Facebook doesn't recognize `localdev.{{my application URL}}` as the URL, and it still gives me the same error code, 191.
2. Once I changed the host file into `{{my application URL}}` without the "localdev." it worked, so this must mean the URLs must match exactly, and not just the domain. Is this true? Anyway, it isn't optimal, because it means I have to change the host file all the time, but it's something you can live with...

Comment: Good questions..It's going to be quite difficult anyway to get realtime updates from facebook to your local machine so I doubt you can do everything if you get it set up.

Comment: @niklasR that was never the problem.. I can get it to work if I change the app url, but then the online version stops working...

Comment: Downvoter please explain

Comment: You don't need to app IDs - just deploy your test app to a different major version to the one that serves live traffic.

Comment: @nick if it's a different version, i have to access it in a different url, which means i will have problems with facebook authentication, no? also, maybe you should write it in answer to prevent clutter.

Comment: @Uri Yes - but developing on localhost will have a different URL to production, too. I didn't submit it as an answer because I'm only addressing your incidental point that you thought you had to use two App IDs.

Comment: @nick not necessarily, if you use the host file you can log in to localhost by typing the regular production app url. you just have to change it back if you want to look at the production app.

Comment: @Uri Sure, but it has the problem you already mentioned of port numbers, not to mention it's a huge pain to do. Using multiple URLs is much better and cleaner. In any case, I wasn't addressing that, only your assertion that you'd need multiple App IDs.

Comment: If all needed is a users facebook ID then there can be a workaround but if you want realtime API access to facebook I don't think you can "stage" the environment since it schecks for cross-site forgery and such to prevent fake apps. I have one app ID at facebook and I see that there is only one setting for where facebook "sends."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 Facebook apps, one with my real URL (for production), and one with http://127.0.0.1/ (for development). Then I have a utility function in my code which checks `self.request.host`, and selects the appropriate app id and secret.

The reason I use http://127.0.0.1/ and not http://localhost/ or http://localhost:8080/ is that I found only http://127.0.0.1/ would work in Internet Explorer (other browsers seemed fine with those other two URLs, provided they matched the Facebook app).

Comment: That's one way to go, upvoted... but it could be problematic if you need the right app id for non user initiated server tasks, or if you have special settings for your app (like open graph stuff). If there won't be any better suggestions, i'll accept.

Comment: @Uri: Server tasks (eg the taskqueue) will also have a self.request.host which you can look up. But yes it does mean having multiple Facebook apps, which need to be configured similarly. However I find it useful to separate dev from prod, so that I can make modifications to dev without risking prod. Actually I use this approach with 3 Facebook apps - http://127.0.0.1/ (dev), http://dev.mysite.com (test/staging), http://www.mysite.com (prod), with http://dev.mysite.com running publicly on app engine, so I can do a final check with the real app engine before going from dev to prod.

Comment: +1 since it's a working solution but isn't this solution exactly what we call a "staging environment"? And can you really do Facebook realtime updates this way? I have only one facebook application per appspot application.

Comment: @Niklas R: My site is fairly light on Facebook integration - it uses Facebook Connect to log users in via Facebook, gets basic profile info, as well as a friends list. I use the javascript API, along with the Python SDK at https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.py. No, it would not work with real-time updates or with anything else which requires Facebook to call your app (eg, server-side fbml).